# What is the maximum range of a BAe 146-300? Can auxiliary fuel tanks be added?

Tags: fuel-tanks, range, bae-146

What is the maximum range of a BAe 146-300? I saw one on Flightradar24.com which started in western France and is still flying non-stop to Greece (flight in progress at the time of posting).

I was really surprised, I guess they probably have an additional fuel tank? I know that some airlines do add extra tanks  to their planes (e.g. on a [B737](http://www.b737.org.uk/fuel.htm#Auxiliary_Fuel_System)) to increase the maximum range; but is it possible on on a BAe 146-300?

[image: Flightradar24.com Screenshot]

Comment: these planes are colloquially known as "smurf jets"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Aerospace_146#Specifications_.28BAe_146-200.29) it has a range of 2909 km and the distance is around 2500 km

[image: google maps measuring FTW]